# Get index of element among siblings ignoring sibling with specific child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a specific use case I can't seem to find an answer to. Given the DOM elements below:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item">
       <div class="foo"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
       <div class="bar"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item selected"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I need to find the index of the `.selected` element in regard to it's siblings. But I need to ignore any siblings that have the `.foo` child element (it will only ever be the direct child).

So typically to find the index of `.item .selected` you could use `$(".item.selected").index()` which gives **4**, but since one item before it has a `.foo` child the correct answer is **3**.

I thought, the best way to go about it was to grab all the siblings *before* the selected element (since siblings after it wouldn't shift it's index) and then count how many have a `.foo` child, and subtract that number from the selected index, so **4-1=3**. I tried to do that like this:

```
var selectedIndex = $(".item.selected").index();
var fooCount = $(".item.selected").prevAll('.item > .foo').length;
var finalIndex = selectedIndex - fooCount;
```

The problem is, fooCount is coming up **0** instead of **3**.

Comment: You can filter the result using http://api.jquery.com/filter/ using this, you can have the foo in any item before or after selected and it would still work

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and remove the preceding elements that have a given child.

```js
const selected = $('.selected');
const foos = selected.prevAll().filter(function() {
  return !($(this).find('.foo').length);
});

console.log(selected.index(), foos.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="foo"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item selected"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector `".item:not(:has(.foo))"` and then loop to find the specific index.

```js
var index = $(".item:not(:has(.foo))")
               .toArray()
               .findIndex(function(item) {
                 return $(item).hasClass('selected');
               });

console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="foo"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item selected"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close.

Change:

```
var fooCount = $(".item.selected").prevAll('.item > .foo').length;
```

… to:

```
var fooCount = $(".item.selected").prevAll('.item:has(.foo)').length;
```

Otherwise, you're looking for a *sibling* with class `.foo`, when you actually want a sibling that has a *child* with class `.foo`.

**Snippet:**

```js
var selectedIndex = $(".item.selected").index();
var fooCount = $(".item.selected").prevAll('.item:has(.foo)').length;
var finalIndex = selectedIndex - fooCount;

console.log(finalIndex);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item">
       <div class="foo"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
       <div class="bar"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item selected"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine:

[:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/): selects all elements that do not match the given selector.

[:has()](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/): reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.

[:index(element)](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element): where element is the DOM element or first element within the jQuery object to look for.

Hence, you can change your code:

```
var selectedIndex = $(".item.selected").index();
```

to:

```
var selectedIndex = $('.item:not(:has(.foo))').index($('.item.selected'));
```

```js
var selectedIndex  = $('.item:not(:has(.foo))').index($('.item.selected'));

console.log(selectedIndex );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="foo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```